# Siri INPlayMediaIntent not working in anything other than english

Tags: ios, localization, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I have a program that handles `INPlayMediaIntent` in an extension. This works fine as long as you are using Siri in english. Switching to another language makes Siri consider the query as a web search. To reproduce, please check out [my demo from github](https://github.com/mickeyl/iOS-Bug-Example-Projects) and have a look at the `Siri-Localized-MediaIntents-Broken` folder.

Then:

- Switch Siri to english
- Edit the extension run scheme to feed Siri with, e.g., "Play Running in SiriTest"
   – Run the extension scheme (might need to chose Siri as the process to run)
- Result is fine, Siri recognizes that you’re talking about the app `SiriTest` and runs the extension (actually the first time it asks you whether it can have access to SiriTest data, but that alone means it's working fine).

Now:

- Switch Siri to german
- Edit the extension run scheme to feed Siri with the query, "Spiele Running in SiriTest“
- Run the scheme
- Result is wrong, Siri does not recognize that SiriTest has been referred and considers this as a web search, thus reporting that it has not found anything meaningful.

Is this a bug (which is what I'm suspecting) or am I dong anything wrong here?

Comment: If you suspect it's a bug, it's best to report it to Apple.

Comment: Just to make sure, it does understand whole sentence? Like you know, after you say it, it types "Spiele Running in SiriTest" without any errors? Issues I've had in the past is that Siri didn't understand different language names when set to certain language.

Comment: Yes, the sentence appears properly understood, but is not treated correctly.

Comment: Try using "Spiele Running auf SiriTest". This is definitely an ugly phrase, but it works on my radio player app. If I use "Spiele ... in ..." Siri thinks I refer to some Apple Music song.